# android waiting on something

Tags: java, android, wait

I was wondering how to make a program pause and wait for an event to finish before starting another event, for example I could have a text to speech that says something and right after that a google voice recognizer should fire, however they both fire at the same time and makes the speech recognizer listen to the text to speech. I tried searching on here about it and found some answers but they were not really clear for me, can anyone help me with it?

here is an example code i tested out :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    tts=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), 
          new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
          public void onInit(int status) {
             if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                 tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                 tts.speak("Welcome", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }               
             }
          });

    if(!(tts.isSpeaking())){
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }
}

private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Up");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        if (matches.contains("list")){
                Intent gotoList = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ListActivity.class );
                startActivity(gotoList);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of **asynchronous events**.

In order to do what you want, the approach is not to "wait" (because everything would then freeze), but to "listen".

When something takes long in Android, such as the Text To Speech, you have to **listen for a event.**

If you look at the docs for the Text To Speech object, you'll find it accepts a listener for different things: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceProgressListener(android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener) and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html

So you'd do (assuming your Text to Speech object is `tts`):

```
tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

  public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
      // The text has been read, do your next action

  }

  public void onError(String utteranceId, int errorCode) {
      // Error reading the text with code errorCode, can mean a lot of things

  }

  public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
      // Reading of a sentence has just started. You could for example print it on the screen

  }
});
```

This is called "subscribing to an event", and is asynchronous because your program can do other things and you'll be notified when "something" (what you have subscribed to) happens.

Then for example when you do

```
tts.speak ("welcome", ....)
```

And it finishes, the method `onDone` in your listener will be called. You can start the voice recognizer there.

Comment: very useful, it didnt solve my problem but with your link and some searching i found out how to exactly do it, thank you very much for this useful info +1